# MAKE ROWS COLUMNS IN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I have query ....

```
SELECT      DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate) AS WeekNumber,
        COUNT (*) as Total
FROM        dbo.MyTable
Group by    DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
ORDER BY    WeekNumber
```

How do I make it so that the week numbers are the Column Headers and the Total as the Row.

Comment: There is no need to shout. You already know you should `pivot`, why ask?

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6349.pivoting

Answer (score 0):

```
--Create table 
CREATE Table dbo.MyTable 
(
idenddate datetime
);
GO
--Insert sample record in table 
Insert into dbo.MyTable select getdate()
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,1,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,2,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,3,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,4,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,5,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,6,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,7,getdate())
Go
Insert into dbo.MyTable select Dateadd(d,12,getdate())
Go

--Optimize query
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsHeader AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Create Column
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'W' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)) 
                    from dbo.MyTable
                    Group by    DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
                    order by DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

--Create Column Header
select @colsHeader = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'W' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)) + ' ''' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)) +''''
                    from dbo.MyTable
                    Group by    DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
                    order by DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colsHeader + ' from 
             (
                SELECT    ''W''+ Convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate))  AS WeekNumber,
                        COUNT (*) as Total
                FROM        dbo.MyTable
                Group by    DATEPART(WEEK,idenddate)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Total)
                for WeekNumber in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXEC(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is a Pivot. This is an example of how to do a pivot table using Microsoft SQL Server. There may be other ways for a different server though.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/

The other way would be to create a stored procedure and generate a temporary table using the rows from the first table, then for each row of the first table (the table that generates columns) loop through the second table values to create an insert statement for the temporary pivot table. Finally select on the temporary pivot table with any filter you need to get the relevant data.

Comment: Even easier with weeks number, juste create a temporary table with week days, from 1 to 52 instead of taking column data from another table. The previous algorithm is still relevant